# Break an integer into even- and odd-indexed bits

Tags: code-golf, integer, binary

## Objective

Given an integer \$n\$ interpreted as two's complement binary, output two integers, namely the integer consisting of \$n\$'s bits at places of \$2^0, 2^2, 2^4, \cdots\$, and the integer consisting of \$n\$'s bits at places of \$2^1, 2^3, 2^5, \cdots\$.

Note that the input may be negative. Since \$n\$ is interpreted as two's complement binary, nonnegative integers start with infinitely many zeros, and negative integers start with infinitely many ones. As a consequence, nonnegative inputs split into nonnegative outputs, and negative inputs split into negative outputs.

## Examples

Here, the integers are represented as decimal.

```
Input, Output even, Output odd
0, 0, 0
1, 1, 0
2, 0, 1
3, 1, 1
4, 2, 0
5, 3, 0
6, 2, 1
7, 3, 1
8, 0, 2
9, 1, 2
10, 0, 3
11, 1, 3
12, 2, 2
13, 3, 2
14, 2, 3
15, 3, 3
-1, -1, -1
-2, -2, -1
-3, -1, -2
-4, -2, -2
```

## Worked Example

Say the input is `43`, or `101011` in binary.

The "even" output selects the bits like this:

```
...0000101011
... ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

which is `...00001`, or `1` in decimal.

The "odd" output selects the bits like this:

```
...0000101011
...^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

which is `...00111`, or `7` in decimal.

## I/O format

Flexible; [default I/O policies](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/89459) apply.

Comment: pardon me for this stupid question - how did you arrive at `3,0` for input of `5` when it's binary representation is `0b_101`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto So `0bxyz` would break to `0bxz` and `0by`.

Comment: I'd like to see a worked example for each of a positive and negative input.

Comment: would it be fine if my program required a + before positive integers? so -2 would stay -2, but 2 would have to be inputted as +2

Comment: @Quadruplay Yes, of course.

Comment: I have 2 solutions, 1 for 8-bit integers, and 1 for 16-bit integers, should i post the 16-bit one, or the smallest one?

Comment: @Quadruplay Post the one that doesn't violate [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/89459) loophole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 12 bytes

```
„¿⌐bU;ᵛB?„¿⌐
```

[Try it Online! (link is to literate version)](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJsIiwiIiwibmVnYXRpdmU/IGlmLXRvcDogYml0d2lzZS1ub3RcbnRvLWJpbmFyeSB1bmludGVybGVhdmUgcGFpciB2ZWM6IGZyb20tYmluYXJ5XG5pbnB1dCBuZWdhdGl2ZT8gaWYtdG9wOiBiaXR3aXNlLW5vdCIsIiIsIi00IiwiMy40LjIiXQ==)

Could be 5 bytes if it wasn't for the negative input requirement.

### Explained

```
negative? if-top: bitwise-not ## „¿⌐
to-binary uninterleave pair vec: from-binary ## bU;ᵛB
input negative? if-top: bitwise-not ## ?„¿⌐
```

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes by tsh

-1B from l4m2

-2B from att

```javascript
f=n=>[p]=n*~n?[f(n>>1)[1]*2|n&1,p]:[n,n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUxdT8MwDHz3r@gTSlq3w8n4VsoPiSKWhXYCVW61IZ4Qf72kzoRkn3139n3G73hJ54/lq@X5fVjX0bHr/RIc17/86kfFfU/aU6jND98QLuHZM3JYXw5wi9VWQFjRNo1wAiucYI/VJsEdVnab98IJHoQTPMq9gSe5N0Al0AKVxLwYecmWlZ@8lNBslVQLbb4sDW12pPNqr6qBdn9VDRy687BMMQ1qp7pa4z/sTqjeMOIRk3Z9mvkyT0M3zSfVRBwz6ILONcfGY5OC1usf)

Comment: `f=n=>[p,q]=n+1>>1?[f(n>>1)|q*2|n&1,p]:[n,n]`

Comment: `n+1>>1` -> `n*~n`

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:[x]*(x*~x+2)or[x&1|(r:=f(x//2))[1]*2,r[0]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3TdNscxJzk1ISFSqsoititTQqtOoqtI0084uiK9QMazSKrGzTNCr09Y00NaMNY7WMdIqiDWJjoZqT0vKLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM1DM00rbgUgKCgKDOvRCNTR0Fd105dRyFNI1NTk4sLTbWuoY6CrikQG-LRBbEJ5lwA)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 54 bytes

<s>*Port of [@l4m2's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272086/91267)*</s> (approach in @l4m2's answer has changed quite a bit)

*-1 byte thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

```python
f=lambda x:[x]*(x*~x+2)or[x%2+f(x//4)[0]*2,f(x//2)[0]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zdJscxJzk1ISFSqsoititTQqtOoqtI0084uiK1SNtNM0KvT1TTSjDWK1jHTAHCMQJxaqOyktv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcPQTNOKSwEICooy80o0MnUU1HXt1HUU0jQyNTW5uNBU6xrqKOiaArEhHl0Qm2DuBQA)

Comment: Save 2 bytes by switching to Python 2 and using `/` instead of `//`.

Comment: Python, 55 bytes: [`f=lambda x:x+x%2and[x%2+f(x//4)[0]*2,f(x//2)[0]]or[x,x]`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zdNscxJzk1ISFSqsKrQrVI0S81KigZR2mkaFvr6JZrRBrJaRDphjBOLE5hdFV-hUxEK1J6XlFylkKmTmKRQl5qWnahgaaFpxKQBBQVFmXolGpo6Cuq6duo5CmkampiYXF5pqXUMdBV1TIDbEowtiE8zBAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 45 bytes

```c
f(x,y)int*y;{*y=x*~x?x&1|2*f(x>>1,&x):x;x=x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvtCsIgGIX/exUvxYY6F9nP3OxG@hOaJZSLtUC31q2bQh8HXnh5znNUfVIqRoM9C8S6gQYx0dB6@vI7X/LnhqZKSs5KT7Ze@NaLOS6tU5eHPkJzH7TtVmeJUNrC9WAdJjAhSDFdDzhTCy3UfC3S0wDnAqrKfqWc7AQGo/iRMS0MtgzKQP701ifT4EWhoZZQaJZu7xYMkpj3H3VGc3wD)

Odd bits are returned directly, while even bits are returned through the pointer in the second argument.

#### Explanation

```c
f(x,                    // recrusive method with integer parameter x
  y)int*y;{             // odd bits are returned; even bits are returned through y
  *y = x * ~x           //   if x * (x - 1) is non zero (i.e. x is not 0 or -1)
      ? x&1 | 2*f(x>>1  //     then y = x&1 | 2*odd_bits(x>>1)
        ,&x)            //          x = even_bits(x>>1)
      : x;              //     else y = x
  x = x;}               //   return x
```

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 22 bytes

Returns *odd* output before *even* output.

```
2/64 2#,/|@\^:\(64#2)\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLszLSNzNRMFLW0a9xiImzitEwM1E20ozh4kowsNLRVzdW0TVSUSnRUa9RT1MvsdJQNDTT1KlR1DUBAHQWDLo=)

`(64#2)\` Get an array of all bits of the integer.
`,/|@\^:\` Magic incantation to repeat the leading bit 65 times. Works something like: *make all bits zero, index into the array of bits, prepend that result to the bits*.
`64 2#` Reshape the length 128 array into a matrix with two columns.
`2/` Convert both columns from base 2.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
»~BṚŒœUḄ~>Ƈ¡
```

A monadic Link that accepts an integer, \$n\$, and yields a pair of non-negative integers, \$e,o\$ (`[even_bits_as_int(n), odd_bits_as_int(n)]`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//wrt@QuG5msWSxZNV4biEfj7Gh8Kh////LTQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##AWEAnv9qZWxsef//wrt@QuG5msWSxZNV4biEfj7Gh8Kh/8OHxZLhuZjhua1q4oCcID0@IOKAnSlZ//9zb3J0ZWQocmFuZ2UoLTQsMTYpLCBrZXk9bGFtYmRhIHg6YWJzKHgpLXgp).

#### How?

```
»~BṚŒœUḄ~>Ƈ¡ - Link: integer, N            e.g.: -42                 42
 ~           - bitwise NOT                        41                -43
»            - {N} max {that}                     41                 42
  B          - convert to binary       [1,0,1,0,0,1]      [1,0,1,0,1,0]
   Ṛ         - reverse                 [1,0,0,1,0,1]      [0,1,0,1,0,1]
    Œœ       - unzip               [[1,0,0],[0,1,1]]  [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
      U      - reverse each        [[0,0,1],[1,1,0]]  [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
       Ḅ     - convert from binary             [1,6]              [0,7]
           ¡ - if...
          Ƈ  - ...keep those for which:
         >   -      greater than {N}?          [1,6] (truthy)        [] (falsey)
        ~    - ...then: bitwise NOT          [-2,-7]              [0,7]
```

Answer (score 5):

## x86 machine code, 18 bytes

```
080497c8 <f>:
 80497c8:       be 55 55 55 55          mov    esi,0x55555555
 80497cd:       c4 e2 7a f5 d6          pext   edx,eax,esi
 80497d2:       f7 d6                   not    esi
 80497d4:       c4 e2 7a f5 c6          pext   eax,eax,esi
 80497d9:       c3                      ret
```

Input is in `eax`, output in `edx:eax`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBBS8QwEIXPya8YFjzZFtdVkD3vXVkED2tZpk1SA2kSmqxk/fHWtKntLl7NIYR5k@/NG3SOt5U6501d930htefq6M7aYwBtbMeFDLRolKlQQYtSU7GlpDWfwJ3M4C48TocSy4MHzkIGHIfLSUq08emRRLwSO@4pHZiRaE/uY5Am9tCzXlNSo1IgLgzHlrFquzjscQQtKvurXhDzzT8Rg@nmMJPMg/QxhrGpNmabv8wBB5o7VZFtM3iiRHFMoIMwXYu@TNa7t@f9Dl5e93CInWW2bOZauX0op10uI8ZsyNjsME7EficqGHqkyWsLBbpafsHqhr3rFSV9/10LhY3r83Zz/wM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⁻Ｅ²↨²⮌Φ⮌↨⁺θ›⁰θ²⁼ι﹪μ²›⁰θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvLCsIwEEX3fkWWE0hB6rI7RaWLSPEPxhowME2aV39/TApunMXMvZw58wfj7JGYR7eW/CjLy0QIcjhM0boMF0wZtHUlgcYVeiXOmEy7T7OZWOPNUq7Kr@54ovoflLhHgw0elQhSKtG3dQ0FKYFVQvt3IQ/LDtr8G1IOzN2Ju42@) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal's base conversion simply negates the result if the input is negated, so I have to convert from one's complement to two's complement. Also, the array has its most significant bit first and I don't have an easy way to slice alternate bits depending on the index of the last bit.

```
Ｎθ                          First input as a number
     ²                      Literal integer `2`
    Ｅ                       Map over implicit range
             θ              Input number
            ⁺               Plus
               ⁰            Literal integer `0`
              ›             Is greater than
                θ           Input number
           ↨                Converted to base
                 ²          Literal integer `2`
          ⮌                 Reversed
         Φ                  Filtered where
                   ι        Outer value
                  ⁼         Equals
                     μ      Inner index
                    ﹪       Modulo
                      ²     Literal integer `2`
        ⮌                   Reversed
      ↨                     Converted from base
       ²                    Literal integer `2`
   ⁻                        Vectorised substract
                        ⁰   Literal integer `0`
                       ›    Is greater than
                         θ  Input number
  Ｉ                         Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 105 bytes

```powershell
param($a)0,1|%{$k=$_
($c=[Convert])::ToInt16(-join($c::ToString($a,2)|% *ft 32 48|% t*y|?{$i++%2-$k}),2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJdb4IwFIbv@RXnoi6gbSLgnDMhMzEu2dWW6Z0xC4M6P6mDuo8Iv52VVvFwsYYm7XPe876nCQfxzdNsxXc7FomUl2QZnMpDmIZ7m4ROl7p560S2AXmzbBIF87FIvngqF85wOBNPiXT7NtuIdaKKFZnKdJ18qE7qOXkL2ksJvge9gTrL9m/@cCLrTqflMbItHCUpysKyRrYFalEY2V0K1efUwKXgNoCnFe4V@FqBQI@C12i5peA3QF8rUMudViAw0CneFdzrFARcM6qPiJkVE08H4S5fJ2FixsVdZl5EmLI1GzHVpDdm/lmH/FnvrFPMgRweRToJoxV7ft/wSMJJC4nkmRyHGadA@BdPJj8HVeSxuoo4vtwgAPUXaH0lMkUFb8jy6mBpwfxlOj5mUuxNzGJkcqo1PUYRzzKo3CobYPyzmQosTGJjrmtohNpldo6rXOroS/GVZ8edhDrCTFqX8Xv@f62WF1ZhlX8)

Takes an integer and returns two shorts

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48

- 6 bytes saved thanks to @ceilingcat and @l4m2.

TIL modern x86-64 has [instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#BMI2_(Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_2)) for this, and they are wrapped in the `_pext_*()` family of compiler intrinsics.

Not the [shortest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272100/11259), but perhaps the fastest.  Probably this can be golfed more, but this is as far as I got.

Returns the even bits in the most significant 16 bits and the odd bits in the least significant 16 bits of the returned int.

```c
#define g _pext_u32(i,~0U/3
f(i){i=g)<<16|g*2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBNasMwEIXX8SmGhBYpsdP8FBOQ7WVv0F0huJIsD8RysJVgSN2jVx2loYE8tNCbp/lmkEyMlH6GVh5OSkPWO4Xtsi78TOkKrQYD@6Me3P603TCMv1fvL9uoYsgvmBueZev0y8w3XIwerYOmRAuMwyUCUqig@L92ur8bfdY2hlYpEV1rVdsBQ8gheRWAkME6FbBYYGBNqJOSMFVEE@ohw/q67RxnIXqG1fBGCmngPsRFQTD@Nzro2NECFZs@KbieDzuNAeP7Sre3YzT6H1kdStP7pCk7Wee2dHjW5D4b9Mnt04ZdSkCCLutf)

Comment: @ceilingcat [48](https://tio.run/##XZBNasMwEIXX8SmGhBYpsdP8FBOQ7WVv0F0huJIsD8RysJVgSN2jVx2loYE8tNCbp/lmkEyMlH6GVh5OSkPWO4Xtsi78TOkKrQYD@6Me3P603TCMv1fvL9uoYsgvmBueZev0y8w3XIwerYOmRAuMwyUCUqig@L92ur8bfdY2hlYpEV1rVdsBQ8gheRWAkME6FbBYYGBNqJOSMFVEE@ohw/q67RxnIXqG1fBGCmngPsRFQTD@Nzro2NECFZs@KbieDzuNAeP7Sre3YzT6H1kdStP7pCk7Wee2dHjW5D4b9Mnt04ZdSkCCLutf)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
±‚àbR2ιíCI0‹i±
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//8Kx4oCaw6BiUjLOucOtQ0kw4oC5acKx//8tMw) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9vc2FiaWX/MTXDnTRMKMKrNDPCqnZ5PyIg4oaSICI/eUT/wrHigJrDoGJSMs65w61DeTDigLlpwrH/fSz/).

**Explanation:**

```python
±              # Bitwise-NOT (-n-1) the (implicit) input
 ‚             # Pair it with the (implicit) input
  à            # Pop and leave the maximum
   b           # Convert it to binary
    R          # Reverse it
     2ι        # Uninterleave it into 2 parts
       í       # Reverse both parts
        C      # Convert the parts from binary-strings to integers
         I0‹i  # If the input was negative:
             ± #  Bitwise-NOT the values in the pair again
               # (after which the pair is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: This seems to give the wrong output for an input of `-3`.

Comment: @Neil Ugh.. Should be fixed with a much more boring (but correct) approach.

Answer (score 3):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>99</s> 87 bytes

```
ćŁďßżTáPűŰďo␞}Ŕˇóĺo␞)űHOPCĺo␔©H±uä‹˙+Vů")J­SHYľüSHYă»Ż°áĂ…ő—Öe[yűš·źą«wvRE¸␔<ćóš™TDCS®xť’ä+ž'€µh
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
s(}}}})a(>{>{<<}`(>>+<<)}`(>+<))$,.^$/~++>$"J*[>~+<;]>aaaa>Y>YJ[<~s+<~s+;]J$-`(<s<s)JR!.<'2.!.<'@--
```

Just barely got it under 100. The program expects a +/- before the integer, and the integer must be 8-bit. There's also a version that's 110 bytes long, but it works pretty much the same, it's just that the bit shifting and negating requires a few characters more:

```
a(>{>{<<}`(>>+<<)b}`(>+<)b)b(<}`(>Y+Y<)>)$,^$/~++$>*.$>IJ[>~>~+`(<+);]J>>aaaaaaaa>Y>YJ[<~+<~+;]JR!.<'2.!.<'@--
```

I'll explain the smaller version:

```
functions:

s(}}}})                   this one shifts a byte 4 bits to the right

a(>{>{<<}`(>>+<<)}`(>+<)) this one shifts the next 2 cells to the left once, 
                          and then shifts the current cell twice, the first shift increments
                          the second next cell if a 1 was lost, the second increments the
                          first next cell
```

```
calculations:
$,.^$/~++>$"J*[>~+<;]>aaaa>Y>YJ[<~s+<~s+;]

$,.^$/                                     take a char of input, output it, xor it with "-",
                                           and divide by self yielding 0 if "-", 1 if not

      ~++>$"                               NOT and increment twice, turning 0 into 1 and vice
                                           versa, then go to next cell, copy the initialized 
                                           "-" to storage, and input an 8-bit integer into 
                                           2nd cell

            J*[>~+<;]                      multiply first cell by "-", and if non-zero, 
                                           NOT and increment the 2nd cell

                     >aaaa                 apply function "a" to 2nd cell 4 times

                          >Y>Y             reverse order of bits of cells 3 and 4

                              J[<~s+<~s+;] if 1st bit is non-zero, apply NOT, "s", and 
                                           increment cells 3 and 4
```

```
printing:
J$-`(<s<s)JR!.<'2.!.<'@--

J$-`(<s<s)                copy 1st cell to storage and if 0 apply "s" to cells 3 and 4

          JR!.<'2.!.<'    clear screen and print:
                          [storage][cell4][space][storage][cell3]

                      @   end program

                       -- initializer data
```

note: if the 1st character is neither + nor -, the program acts as if it received a +

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.10.0, 22 bytes

```
↙2▽2⍜⌵(⊕°⋯◿2⇡⧻.⊂⋯):<0.
```

### [Explanation + See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oaZMuKWvTLijZzijLUo4oqVwrDii6_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)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 79 bytes

```java
int[]f(int n){return new int[]{n*~n<0?f(n>>2)[0]*2|n%2:n,n*~n<0?f(n>>1)[0]:n};}
```

It's been a while since I've used a recursive approach in Java. Perhaps an iterative lambda with String return could be shorter, but I'm not sure.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rY@xboMwFEV3vuIJqZIdagsIXXCg6gd0yogY3ASqR8kjMiZVROmvU4dmqKpKWTq94eie@26jT1o0@7d51@q@h2eNNHoAvdUWdzAj2aKsmTtAfDSVHQwBVe@wgJFWn7QJH2tGeR7zIixX8QfdxSnd/yTRhaQ0qWlWnpMfh5fWya8dpw73cHC9bGsN0mtRan55AaDuzNKMWahwk0UPCoOALwhge@5tdZDdYOXRxWxLDAM/BT9o3CQ5WGzlkzH63EvbfZuZG8I5V7/kIlKYZyJRKMR/2f/I@8n6Vj5ZXwWTN81f)

**Explanation:**

```java
int[]f(int n){         // Recursive method with integer parameter & integer-array return:
  return new int[]{    //  Return a new integer-array, with two items:
    n*~n<0?            //   If `n*(-n-1)` is negative:
      f(n>>2)          //    Do a recursive call with `n` bitwise right-shifted by 2
             [0]       //    Take its singular result
                *2     //    Multiply it by 2
                  |    //    Bitwise-OR it by:
                   n%2 //     `n` modulo-2
    :                  //   Else (`n*(-n-1)` is 0 instead):
     n,                //    Simply use `n` as is
    n*~n<0?            //   Repeat the same if-statement:
      f(n>>1)          //    Do a recursive call to `n` bitwise right-shifted by 1 instead
             [0]       //    And take its singular result
    :n};}              //   With a similar else-block
```